# passing username and password to JWT Token Controller through an Angular 2 login form

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-jwt

I have an angular 2 login form and I am trying to call a JWT Token Controller through an API call.

My user.service.ts is as follows :-

```
login(username, password) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let credentials = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
  console.log(username, password);
  return this._http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/jwt', credentials, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map((res) => {
      if (res.success) {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
      }

      return res.success;
    });
}
```

When I do the console.log(username, password); I am getting the correct username and password entered in the form.

Then I have the Controller as follows :-

```
      [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string username, string password)
  {

  //code here

  }
```

My problem is that username and password is always null.

I have tried to do a post with Postman to 'http://localhost:5000/api/jwt' with the username and password and it works fine.

How can I pass the username and password to the controller from the Angular 2 form?

Thanks for your help and time

Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a wrong Content-Type header, it must be JSON:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Also make sure that you create a valid JSON object (`JSON.stringify({ username, password })` is invalid and you are getting a javascript error to the console saying that this is broken):

```
let credentials = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
```

And last but not least introduce a view model to match this structure:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(LoginViewModel loginModel)
```

Comment: I tried what you said Darin, and changed my get to         public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromForm] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
however I am still getting null in both username and Password

Comment: my ApplicationUser is exactly like your LoginViewModel

Comment: You should not use `[FromForm]` but rather `[FromBody]` in this case.